# Passing variables through events c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, variables, events

Sorry if this looks kind of rookie :3 ... I don't have much experience on C#, but I really like to code on C#, I think it's a very flexible and friendly object-oriented language.

So well.
I'm trying to pass variables through button clicks, in order to be able to make an insert to a database with the values obtained of button clicks. I have several buttons which recycle the "product" value to a different string, in a natural language approach this would be that:

If I click certain "product" the variable product would gain the name of the button, following of this I would click the "quantity" button and that would give me the quantity number, following this the program would make an insert to the DB with those values. But I'm doubtful of how to recycle this values depending on the buttons clicked.

In brief, the code I have is the following:

```
    private String product;
    private int quantity;
    private char prodchosen;
    private char quantitychosen;

    private void Product_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      prodchosen = 'Y';
      product = "Beer";
    }


    private void Product2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      prodchosen = 'Y';
      product = "Juice";
    }

    public void bttn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      quantitychosen = 'Y';
      quantity = 1;
      if (prodchosen == 'Y' && quanitychosen == 'Y')
      {
       MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=***;username=root;password=***");
       mcon.Open();
       string insert = "INSERT INTO accounts product, quantity VALUES" + product + " , " + quantity;


       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insert, mcon);
       MessageBox.Show("Product was succesfully added");
     }
     else {
       MessageBox.Show("Quantity and product not recognized");
     }
```

After being inserted into the database, these values will be showed in a gridview, the select statement will be delimited by a combobox selectedindex value like:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        clientchosen = 'Y';
        client_id = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

        MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=***;username=root;password=***");
        mcon.Open();

        char open = 'Y';

        int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        Object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

        string select2 = "SELECT * FROM account where client_id = " + selectedIndex + " and open = " + open;

        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(select2, mcon);

        object result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

So far I haven't been able to make a successful insert, not even to show the messagebox, I'll appreciate much any comments you have about this issue.

Comment: Insert query is wrong...use INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

Comment: What happens when you debug it? Are there errors, I mean your sql statement is missing "(" and ")" around the values

Comment: @DDave The insert is fine. You have to specify column names if you're not inserting data into every column. Adding parentheses would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try With This

```
SqlConnection dbconnect = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=***;username=root;password=***");
SqlCommand cmd;

    try
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO accounts(product, quantity) VALUES(@prod, @quan)", dbconnect);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod", Your_Text_Box.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quan", Your_Text_Box.Text);
        dbconnect.Open();
    }
```

This is the way, I Insert values into database. Works Well and Good for Me

Comment: I would suggest adding some explaination on what you are doing/suggesting?

Comment: @Njack
We can do it. It's the way by which we get the results. I usually prefer going like this. It's to check, whether the data is inserted or Not. On the Top Left Corner, we will get '1', which states. Data is inserted

Comment: I guess OP is having winform/wpf application, `Response.Write` may be invalid in this instance.

Comment: @Hari Yes, You are Right. I explained with the web application concepts.

Comment: Also provide an explanation, you parameterized the query which is right thing to do, so include those points and let OP know what is right and what is not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. This is an essay for a point of sales simulator along with a mysql database; I have done this on Java before but never on C#

Comment: , it's a very long coding and design I have done so far, that's why I try to keep the example short since I'm trying to keep all the functional parts of the program on a single windows form... Which lead to a very robust -still non fully functional- coding... This is why I need to understand how to pass variables through methods. But I think you were right on the SQL syntax. Although I'm still not able to make a successful insert on the DB. I'll keep on trying.

Answer (score 2):

I think your SQL is not quite right, the columns and values clauses need parentheses and the string value needs quotes. Try this:

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO accounts(product, quantity) " +
                "VALUES('" + product + "' , " + quantity + ")";
```

Comment: Product might be a number despite being a string variable and parentheses are not required. I would agree though, product probably requires the apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Edited for more elaboration after reading other answers. A parameterized query is a great idea. Look into why that is the case.

Your SQL won't work because you are missing a space after VALUES. The product parameter after it won't be recognized and your insert will not work.

You never execute your command. Execute it with

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Feel free to grab the return value from the above statement if you like - it will return number of rows affected.